# Operator section for applicative with <$> and <*>

Tags: haskell, applicative, operator-sections

Consider functions of type `a -> b -> c`, and the applicative values `a1, a2 :: (Applicative f) => f a`.

I wish to construct a function which may be applied to functions of type `a -> b -> c` to obtain values of type `Applicative f :: f c`.  I can do this in the following way:

```
g :: (Applicative f) => (a -> b -> c) -> f c
g = \f -> f <$> a1 <*> a2
```

(The explicit lambda is deliberate, as I am considering the construction of this function at any level, not just the top level).

If I try to write `g` in point-free style:

```
g = (<$> a1 <*> a2)
```

I get the following compile error:

```
The operator `<$>' [infixl 4] of a section
    must have lower precedence than that of the operand,
      namely `<*>' [infixl 4]
    in the section: `<$> gen1 <*> gen2'
```

I *could* write this point-free implementation:

```
g = flip (flip liftA2 a1) a2
```

but I feel that this is less readable, and it is simpler to refactor the infix function-based implementation to, e.g., add another argument, than changing the above to use `liftA3`.

One can write a chain of compositions:

```
g = (<*> a2) . (<$> a1)
```

This achieves point-free style and it is simple to add arguments - but they get *prepended* on the left instead of appended on the right, so you lose the correspondence with the function type `(a -> b -> c)`.  Furthermore, with more arguments you end up with a much longer expression than just using a lambda as in the first implementation.

So, is there are nice, terse way to write the section I desire, or am I stuck with a lambda?

Comment: in Scala you could have `_ <$> a <*> b` but Haskell has no such syntax.

Comment: @ErikAllik That's interesting syntax! I wonder if someone's written a template-haskell extension for it. That'd be great.

Comment: but `_` has already been taken by typed holes; perhaps something similar though; although the lambda syntax is quite fine.

Answer (score 8):

`<*>` operates on the result of `<$>`, so:

```
g = (<*> a2) . (<$> a1)
```

Comment: @frasertweedale: In that case, I’d just use your first method. It’s not as if it has to be a lambda, though. `g f = f <$> a1 <*> a2`

Comment: @frasertweedale: Even when it’s not just the top level, you can use `let` etc.. Less verbosity doesn’t mean more clarity.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not really convinced pointfree can be made better than using an explicit argument here, but a couple more ideas:

- You can use `flip` infix:

  ```
  g = liftA2 `flip` a1 `flip` a2
  ```
- You can use `>>>` from `Control.Category`, which is `.` flipped:

  ```
  g = (<$> a1) >>> (<*> a2)
  ```